# Вывод поля из другого запроса

Tags: python, django-admin

Есть небольшой код. Нужно  отобразить дополнительное поле в `list_display`. Допустим, есть уникальность `exten`. Делаем запрос с помощью `MySQLdb` и подставляем результат в `list_display`. Итого, получатся вывод два или три поля.

Типа `list_display = ('exten')` выводит одно поле, делаем запрос по значению `exten` и выводим другие поля не использую в `models` `ForeignKey`.

```
class extensions_table(models.Model):
    exten = models.CharField(max_length=20,db_column="exten")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' %(self.exten)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'extensions_table'
        verbose_name = "EXTEN"
        verbose_name_plural = "EXTEN"

class extensions_search(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('exten',)
    list_display = ('exten',)
```

Comment: Ваш код просто ужасен. На чем вы писали до того как попробовали себя в питоне?

Comment: Это первый код был, как умел, так и писал)

Comment: Ну знаете, мой первый код на Джанго-Питоне даст прикурить вашему. Вы видно документацию вообще не открывали ни по джанге, ни по питону. Элементарные код-стайл правила не выполняются.

Конкретно по вашему запросу. Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите сделать. Опишите более подробно. 

И добавьте в код пробелов - спасите глаза участников комьюнити.

Comment: перечитал 5 раз не понял что вы хотите? вы в курсе что в картеж list_display можно засовывать функции? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display 3-й пример. Вам это нужно?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display
то что нужно!!!